# Given a database of flights, find destination place with longest flight time for each origin city

Tags: sql, sqlite, azure-sql-database

Given the `Flight` table:

```
Flights (
    fid, 
    year, 
    month_id, 
    day_of_month, 
    day_of_week_id, 
    carrier_id, 
    flight_num, 
    origin_city, 
    origin_state,
    dest_city,
    dest_state, 
    departure_delay, 
    taxi_out,
    arrival_delay,
    canceled, 
    actual_time, 
    distance
)
```

I need to find, for each city, the destination(s) with **longest flight time**.

I am having a hard time with subqueries.

**My attempt:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT origin_city, dest_city, MAX(actual_time) 
GROUP BY origin_city
```

But I know that is wrong. Any guidance is appreciated

Comment: Your attempt is correct with SQLite 3.7.11 or later (the DISTINCT is superfluous). But for what databases do you actually want the answer?

Answer (score 0):

This will produce a list of origin cities, with the destination cities with the longest flight times.

**EDIT:** Added *GROUP BY* to main query, and *order by/limit* to sub-query to eliminate duplicate origin_cities.

```
SELECT
    f.`origin_city`,
    f.`origin_state`,
    f.`dest_city`,
    f.`desc_state`,
    f.`actual_time`
FROM (
    SELECT 
        `origin_city`,
        `origin_state`,
        max(`actual_time`) as `max_time` 
    FROM `Flights` 
    GROUP BY `origin_city`,`origin_state` 
    ORDER BY `max_time` DESC) a
JOIN `Flights` f
ON f.`origin_city` = a.`origin_city`
    AND f.`origin_state` = a.`origin_state`
    AND f.`actual_time` = a.`max_time`
GROUP BY f.`origin_city`,f.`origin_state`
```

Comment: thanks. Do you know how I can remove  duplicates of the same origin/destination city pairs?

Comment: so I am using Azure and LIMIT doesn't work. Do you know how to replace that statement with TOP?

Comment: So why is your question tagged with MySQL?

Comment: I apologize it is a database class I thought that was the same thing. I used sqlite for the previous assignment and it worked. But in this assignment we are using azure it seems to have some differences with sqlite

Comment: So, please remove the tags that don't apply.

Comment: Also, try it without the __LIMIT 0,1__ -- See edit answer, and mark as accepted if it works.

Comment: here is the error I get

Failed to execute query. Error: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified

Comment: So, why haven't you looked up examples for top, offset, etc and applied it to the query?

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(actual_time) FROM FLIGHTS WHERE origin_city=xxxxx";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo  $row["dest_city"];
 }
```

Wrap the above code in a loop incase you need destination city for every origin city.

Comment: That doesn't provide the destination city with the longest flight time.

Comment: thanks for the response but I am sure that is not the SQLite  we've been learning in lecture. This solution is supposed to be done with query and subqueries. Not for loops